# How to Overlap Div with Hero Image for Material-Design Look?

Tags: html, css, material-design

I am trying to make this layout look a little bit more material ([like this site](https://codetheweb.blog/tags/#CSS)) where the first div overlaps the hero image. I have tried setting the margin in `.about-inner` to -100px to try and bring it up but then it gets a bit messed up when shrunk to mobile size. Is there an easy way to do this that I am missing?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kq0x48fc/

```
<section class="hero">
      <div class="hero-inner">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum<br>dolor sit amet.</h1>
      </div>
</section>

<div class="main-outer">

        <div class="about-inner">
          <h3>「 About 」</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. </p>
        </div>

         <div class="clients-inner">
    <h3>「 Clients 」</h3>
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div>
        <img src="./Assets/Clients/logo.jpg" alt="1" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="./Assets/Clients/logo.jpg" alt="2"  />
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="./Assets/Clients/logo.jpg" alt="3"  />
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="./Assets/Clients/logo.jpg" alt="4"  />
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="./Assets/Clients/logo.jpg" alt="5"  />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you're applying the negative margin to the wrong element. You should apply it to the first child after the `.hero`.

To `.about-inner`.

Also, your vertical centering technique, used in the second section, which centers the two elements in the space of a full viewport height, is affecting this on wider (and taller) screens. To disable it, simply remove the `min-height` from `.main-outer`:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', serif;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 600;
}

h6 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', serif;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-weight: 200;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
  /* align horizontal */
  align-items: center;
  /* align vertical */
}

.hero {
  /* Sizing */
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 60vh;
  /* Flexbox Stuff */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  /* Text styles */
  text-align: center;
  /* Background styles */
  background-color: red;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  background: white;
  padding: 5px;
}

.flex-container>* {
  margin: auto;
}

.flex-container img {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 5px;
}

.main-outer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: safe center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.main-outer>* {
  width: 80vw;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), 0 5px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .07), 0 1px 14px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .06)
}

.about-inner {
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 80vw;
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.clients-inner {
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.about-inner h3,
.clients-inner h3 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding-top: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}

.about-inner p,
.clients-inner p {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0 10vw 1em;
  line-height: 2em;
}

.hero h1 {
  /* Text styles */
  font-size: 3em;
  color: white;
  /* Margins */
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section class="hero">
  <div class="hero-inner">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum<br>dolor sit amet.</h1>
  </div>
</section>

<div class="main-outer">

  <div class="about-inner">
    <h3>「 About 」</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. </p>
  </div>

  <div class="clients-inner">
    <h3>「 Clients 」</h3>
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div>
        <img src="./Assets/Clients/logo.jpg" alt="1" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="./Assets/Clients/logo.jpg" alt="2" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="./Assets/Clients/logo.jpg" alt="3" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="./Assets/Clients/logo.jpg" alt="4" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="./Assets/Clients/logo.jpg" alt="5" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've also applied a few more tweaks to it:

- changed `100px` horizontal padding to `10vw`
- added some `bottom-padding` to `hero` to counter the negative margin of the following element
- used `100%` as width of `.hero` instead of `100vw` to get rid of the horizontal bar (which is caused by `body` having a margin on Stack Overflow snippets).
- applied a soft `box-shadow` to the card-like elements

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative margins to pull stuff over the element above...

```
.main-outer {
    margin-top: -100px;
}
```

Or you can use the hero image as the body background with `no-repeat` and place the content however far down the page you want.

Here's an example of a simpler way to structure your page
the `.page` div represents your body.

```css
.page {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: tan;
  }
  
.hero {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40%;
  background: blue url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1523575518836-9166d367179f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2534&q=80) top center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.content {
  background-color: white;
  min-height: 600px;
  margin: -100px auto 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="hero"></div>
  <div class="content">
    Some content
  </div>
</div>
```